# Adding multiple library projects with same support library having different versions creates issues

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-facebook

I am developing an app containing integration with facebook and  providing sharing and other facility through a third party library named socialize.I am using both of these sdk as library project.when i am attaching my project with this library project is shows me that there are two different android-support.v4 library are given in both of these project.However when i try removing any of them the corresponfing  library project is showing me error in its java files.I don't know how to make all of these project referencing same support library.Is there any way i could find that which version of support library is best compatible in my project  and library projects.

Comment: Update the support library for all projects to point to the last release.